# React PWA offline support not working on sub URLs

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am working on a PWA which has multiple URLs using reactjs and workbox ,
My app is working correctly online and offline but if the user is offline and hit the refresh button other than the root URL then the little dinosaur shows up.

I tried to cache the all URLs dynamically by using the following code

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
new RegExp('/'),
workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'dynamic-URLs',
    plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxEntries: 50
        })
    ]
}));
```

it is working and caching the URLs but only after i refresh the page on a particular URL

can someone help me with this issue ,  or is there any other way to handle this kind of problem

[Here is the screenshot of my app's log after offline refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJvUQ.png)

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the description of the console after refereshing

Comment: I have Solved This issue by adding registerNavigationRoute to my appshell,
Below is the code for it:-

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/app-shell.html')

Thank You

Comment: What is this file app-shell.html refers to